# How to change the font style for embedded MathML in the output PDF?

Tags: apache-fop, mathml

I am new to Apache FOP and I need to change the default font style to times font in the PDF output from FOP

**My fop.xconf** :

```
    <fop version="1.0"> 
    <renderers>
       <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>

                <font embed-url="file:///C:/Windows/Fonts/Times New Roman/times.ttf" name="Times New Roman">
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="roman" weight="normal"/>
                </font>

                <font embed-url="file:///C:/Windows/Fonts/Times New Roman/timesbd.ttf" name="Times New Roman">
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                </font>

                <font embed-url="file:///C:/Windows/Fonts/Times New Roman/timesi.ttf" name="Times New Roman">
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                </font>

                <font embed-url="file:///C:/Windows/Fonts/Times New Roman/timesbi.ttf" name="Times New Roman">
                    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                </font>

            </fonts>
       </renderer>
    </renderers>
    </fop>
```

**My FO file to test:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
            <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:wrapper>
            <fo:block font-family="Times New Roman">
                <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline">
                        <msub>
                            <mi>σ</mi>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi>z</mi>
                            </mrow>
                        </msub>
                        <mo>=</mo>
                        <munder>
                            <mrow>
                                <munder>
                                    <mrow>
                                        <mi mathvariant="normal">l</mi>
                                        <mi mathvariant="normal">i</mi>
                                        <mi mathvariant="normal">m</mi>
                                    </mrow>
                                    <mrow/>
                                </munder>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mo>Δ</mo>
                                <mi>A</mi>
                                <mo rspace="0.25pt" lspace="0.25pt">→</mo>
                                <mn>0</mn>
                            </mrow>
                        </munder>
                        <mspace width="0.33em"/>
                        <mfrac>
                            <mrow>
                                <mo>Δ</mo>
                                <msub>
                                    <mi>F</mi>
                                    <mrow>
                                        <mi>z</mi>
                                    </mrow>
                                </msub>
                            </mrow>
                            <mrow>
                                <mo>Δ</mo>
                                <mi>A</mi>
                            </mrow>
                        </mfrac>
                    </math>
                </fo:instream-foreign-object>
            </fo:block>
            </fo:wrapper>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

So these are my files that I am using to get the PDF out in Times New Roman font, but the fonts not changing in the output.pdf

Kindly suggest any way to accomplish this

The code I am running in command line is : `fop -fo test.fo -c fop.xconf -pdf 1233.pdf`

Comment: I suggest adding a mathml tag, all font references are done out of mathml, are you using the jeuclid plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using jeuclid ! can you show any example on your suggestion

Comment: Sorry, I have no specific knowledge about fop/jeuclid and font handling, just try adding the mathml tag by editing the question to attract people who know more. That being said, I'd try to e.g. replace "Times New Roman" by "TimesNewRoman" in the font-triplets, you can also add these as new triplets inside the `<font embed-url...` config elements, just in case jeuclid would use that name...- is the output showing Times at all? or sans serif?

Comment: Thanks for your info, I will try that and let you know, and output not showing times

Comment: Output not showing time? See the [jeuclid fop readme](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/jeuclid-fop/), it states "MathML specified inline will take the following attributes from the surrounding .fo context...Name of the fonts used. " so put a `font-family="Times New Roman"` in the `fo:block` surrounding your mathml

Comment: As @StefanHegny said, the problem is that your FO file never states that you want to use the "Times New Roman" font that you configured.

Comment: Hi Stefan and Ifurini, Thanks for your suggestions, I have tried as you said, but didn't work, kindly check the command line log :

Apr 12, 2017 10:16:56 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent

WARNING: Font "Times New Roman,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".

Apr 12, 2017 10:16:57 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent 

INFO: Rendered page #1.